# Get System Unique UUID using GOLANG

Tags: linux, go

I was trying to figure out a way to get the system unique UUID.

like generated by

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

I tried using `github.com/satori/go.uuid` but each time I execute it, 
it gives me a new UUID.

The code that I am using is as below.

```
func main() {

    u2, err := uuid.NewV4()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("UUIDv4: %s\n", u2)
}
```

Comment: Your code creates a new v4 UUID--this is entirely unrelated to the system uuid reported by dmidecode.  If you want the system uuid, you need to read the /proc filesystem (or your OS equivalent).

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ochapman/godmi

Comment: Thanks will check and revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "github.com/dselans/dmidecode" for getting the System UUID.
[dmidecode](https://github.com/dselans/dmidecode/)

Simple Code snippet is below

```
func main() {
    dmi := dmidecode.New()

    if err := dmi.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to get dmidecode information. Error: %v\n", err)
    }

    byNameData, _ := dmi.SearchByName("UUID")
    fmt.Printf("uuid2: %v ", byNameData)

}
```